# Sphinx 3 index a relational database

Tags: sphinx

Here is my Database scheme:

```
Restaurants -> id, title
Categories  -> id, restaurant_id, type(enum: cafe, restaurant, fastfood, burger, chiness)
Reviews     -> id, restaurant_id, body
```

**Reviews** belong to a **restaurant** and a **restaurant** belongs to **multiple categories**

how can we query reviews belong to a category?

here is the current config:

```
sql_query = select reviews.id as id, reviews.body as body, restaurants.url as url, restaurants.id as restaurant_id from reviews inner join restaurants on(restaurants.id = reviews.restaurant_id)

sql_attr_multi  = uint category_id from query; SELECT restaurant_id, categories.id as category_id FROM categories
```

the problem is in the sql_attr_multi it replaces restaurant_id by the reviews.id! it doesn't know the restaurant_id in the sql_attr_multi and it thinks we mean the reviews.id by it!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the first column in the resultset in sql_attr_multi, should be the 'document_id' from the main query. In your example the document_id is reviews.id, but then seem to use restaruant_id in the MVA. It can't match arbitrary attributes like that.

So would actually need something like

```
sql_attr_multi = uint category_id from query; \
    SELECT reviews.id, categories.id as category_id \
    FROM categories \
    INNER JOIN reviews ON(reviews.restaurant_id = categories.restaurant_id) \
    ORDER BY reviews.id
```

To get the review id to perform the join. Split into lines to make it easier to read. Have found it best to explictly order the rows via document_id.

But that still wouldnt let you query via the 'type' , ie 'cafe' etc, because your 'categories.id' seems to be a unique id per restaurant anyway.
(ie each cafe would would a different categories.id!)

So actually seems you would want the 'type' as the MVA value. MVAs are numberic (not string), but luckily, enum is easily converted to a integer!

```
sql_attr_multi = uint category_type from query; \
    SELECT reviews.id, type+0 \
    FROM categories \
    INNER JOIN reviews ON(reviews.restaurant_id = categories.restaurant_id) \
    ORDER BY reviews.id
```

The column names in the `sql_attr_multi` dont matter, just uses first column as document_id, second as the MVA value.

THen knowing cafe (for example) is the first value in enum, its 1. So query reivews for cafe... (burger would be 4 for example)

```
SphinxQL> SELECT * FROM myindex WHERE MATCH('keyword') AND category_type = 1
```